# PySpark Python Sorting dataframe using a column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, regexp-replace

So I have 2 questions which I think should be basic for people experienced in PySpark, but I can't seem to solve them.

Sample entries in my `csv` file are-

```
"dfg.AAIXpWU4Q","1"
"cvbc.AAU3aXfQ","1"
"T-L5aw0L1uT_OfFyzbk","1"
"D9TOXY7rA_LsnvwQa-awVk","2"
"JWg8_0lGDA7OCwWcH_9aDc","2"
"ewrq.AAbRaACr2tVh5wA","1"
"ewrq.AALJWAAC-Qku3heg","1"
"ewrq.AADStQqmhJ7A","2"
"ewrq.AAEAABh36oHUNA","1"
"ewrq.AALJABfV5u-7Yg","1"
```

I create the following dataframe-

```
>>> df2.show(3)
+-------+----+
|user_id|hits|
+-------+----+
|"aYk...| "7"|
|"yDQ...| "1"|
|"qUU...|"13"|
+-------+----+
only showing top 3 rows
```

First, is this the right way to convert `hits` column to `IntegerType()`? Why are all values becoming `null`?

```
>>> df2 = df2.withColumn("hits", df2["hits"].cast(IntegerType()))
>>> df2.show(3)
+-------+----+
|user_id|hits|
+-------+----+
|"aYk...|null|
|"yDQ...|null|
|"qUU...|null|
+-------+----+
only showing top 3 rows
```

Second, I need to sort this list in descending order with respect to `hits` column. So, I tried this-

```
>>> df1 = df2.sort(col('hits').desc())
>>> df1.show(20)
```

But I get the following error-

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Input row doesn't have expected number of values required by the schema. 2 fields are required while 18 values are provided.`

I'm guessing it's due to the fact that I create my dataframe using-

```
>>> rdd = sc.textFile("/path/to/file/*")
>>> rdd.take(2)
['"7wAfdgdfgd","7"', '"1x3Qdfgdf","1"']
​
>>> my_df = rdd.map(lambda x: (x.split(","))).toDF()

>>> df2 = my_df.selectExpr("_1 as user_id", "_2 as hits")
>>> df2.show(3)
+-------+----+
|user_id|hits|
+-------+----+
|"aYk...| "7"|
|"yDQ...| "1"|
|"qUU...|"13"|
+-------+----+
only showing top 3 rows
```

And I'm guessing there's extra commas in some rows. How do I avoid this - or what's the best way to read this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, w.r.t @SanBan answer, I came up with the following results-

```
>>> rdd = sc.textFile("/home/jsanghvi/work/buffer/*")

>>> schema =  StructType([StructField ("user_id", StringType(), True), StructField ("hits", StringType(), True)])

>>> my_rdd = rdd.map(lambda x: x.replace("'","")).map(lambda x: x.split(",")).map(lambda x: (x[0],x[1]))

>>> my_rdd2 = my_rdd.map(lambda x: str(x).replace("'","").replace("(", "").replace(")", "")).map(lambda x: x.split(",")).map(lambda x: (x[0],x[1]))

>>> df1 = spark.createDataFrame(my_rdd2, schema)

>>> dfx = df1.sort(col('hits').desc())

>>> dfx.show(5)
+----------------+--------------------+                                     
|         user_id|                hits|
+----------------+--------------------+
|"AUDIO_AUTO_PLAY| EXPANDABLE_AUTOM...|
|       "user_id"|             "_col1"|
| "AAESjk66lDk...|              "9999"|
| "ABexsk6sLlc...|              "9999"|
| "AAgb1k65pHI...|              "9999"|
+----------------+--------------------+

# removing garbage rows
>>> dfx = df2.filter(~col("hits").isin(["_col1", "EXPANDABLE_AUTOM..."]))
```

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**

-- Adding file read and split

looking at example above, created a file like this

```
'"7wAfdgdfgd","7"'
'"1x3Qdfgdf","1"'
'"13xxyyzzsdff","13"'
```

--Please note the `'` to make all the lines as single string
Now the code to read it :

```
scala> val myRdd = sc.textFile("test_file.dat")
myRdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = test_file.dat MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at <console>:24
// please check the type of RDD , here it is string
// We need to have Iterable[tuple(String,String)] to convert it into Dataframe

scala> myRdd.map(x => x.replace("'","")).map(x => x.split(",")).map( x => (x(0),x(1)))
res0: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String)] = MapPartitionsRDD[4] at map at <console>:26

// Finally
    scala> myRdd.map(x => x.replace("'","")).map(x => x.split(",")).map( x => (x(0),x(1))).toDF("user_id","hits").show(false)
+--------------+----+
|user_id       |hits|
+--------------+----+
|"7wAfdgdfgd"  |"7" |
|"1x3Qdfgdf"   |"1" |
|"13xxyyzzsdff"|"13"|
+--------------+----+
```

**END of UPDATE**

since you are new(or otherwise), I recommend/practice running actual `ANSI sql` instead of `pyspark.sql.functions`. It makes easy to maintain + there is no advantage of using `sql.functions` over `ansi sql`.
Obviously, you need to know sql/columns functions provided by spark as I used `split`,`orderBy` and `cast` in answer.
Since you did not provide with content of `text file`, here is my take and all the **3 answers** in one SQL

```
    myDf = spark.createDataFrame([("abc","7"),("xyz","18"),("lmn","4,xyz")],schema=["user_id","hits"])
myDf.show(20,False)
+-------+-----+
|user_id|hits |
+-------+-----+
|abc    |7    |
|xyz    |18   |
|lmn    |4,xyz|
+-------+-----+

myDf.createOrReplaceTempView("hits_table")
```

**SQL + Result**

```
    spark.sql("select user_id, cast(split(hits,',')[0] as integer) as hits from hits_table order by hits desc ").show(20,False)
    +-------+----+
    |user_id|hits|
    +-------+----+
    |xyz    |18  |
    |abc    |7   |
    |lmn    |4   |
    +-------+----+
```

Comment: can you create the dataframe from an RDD like I did? I think the line `my_df = rdd.map(lambda x: (x.split(","))).toDF()` is the root cause of my issue. I get the error `Input row doesn't have expected number of values required by the schema. 2 fields are required while 18 values are provided.` You're creating a dataframe out of simple data.

Comment: @kev, can you paste a sample of raw data , please ?

Comment: @kev, please check my updated answer on Reading as RDD ,splitting it and converting to dataframe. Also shown how the type changes with each operation

Comment: can you please give me answers for Python?

Comment: @kev Does not Python uses “[ ]” to get index of a list ? Will () work ?

Comment: Also to use toDF create a structType object with two structFields each having type string

Comment: can you check the new answer, I've posted the results